# Doesn't Heroku allow apps access other ports than 80 (default port)

Tags: node.js, heroku, graphql, amazon-rds, postgraphile

Whole day I struggled for deployment on Heroku. It's a node based application that uses postgraphile for graphql query to AWS RDS PostgreSQL.

Deploy on Heroku was successfully done. DB was successfully migrated via Flyway.

And also I can see the web pages on the url generated by Heroku.
But the issue is I can't get any response for graphql query. It sends a request to postgraphile process which binds on port 5000 by default as you know. So the query url is like this.

https://appname.herokuapp.com:5000/graphql

But it doesn't respond at all. What would be an alternative to go around this?
Or Is there any solution on Heroku yet?

Any idea would be appreciated so much.

Comment: No, you cannot listen on multiple ports on Heroku. However, you may be able to route requests from a dedicated endpoint on your non-GraphQL API to your GraphQL API. It's all just POST requests, right?

Comment: Hello, Chris.. thanks for your comment. Yeah, just same thought I was in. But not sure if they will allow this or not. Have you ever done like that? However, if possible, have a lot of things to make change... Disaster!